# htmlspecialchars error when using multiple translation files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on translations for my laravel project. It's all working fine, but only when I'm working with just one translation file.

I'm trying to keep things organised, and for that purpose I had the idea to have one translation file for the side-wide components (login/logout links, back buttons, stuff like that) and then introduce other translation files for more specific things, such as translating components found on your profile's dashboard.

Here are, for example, my English translation files:

**general.php**

```
return [
    "login" => "Login",
    "register" => "Register",
    "logout" => "Logout",
    "back" => "Back",
    "postBy" => "Posted by",
    "name" => "Name",
    "email" => "E-Mail Address",
    "pass" => "Password",
    "confirmPass" => "Confirm Password",
    "rememberMe" => "Remember Me", 
    "forgotPass" => "Forgot Your Password?",
];
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php

return [
    "title" => "Your Messages",
    "header" => "Message",
    "create" => "Add Message",
    "edit" => "Edit",
    "delete" => "Delete",
];
```

I'm already getting errors by doing this, without even using it in my **dashboard.blade.php** file. The error I get is:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, array given (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\messageboard\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\messageboard\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

while I haven't even attempted to call it with something like `{{ __('dashboard.title') }}`. I'm at a loss as to what's causing this error.

As requested, here is the view causing the error. I'm getting the same error no matter what page is loaded, so I'm assuming that it'll be this very view as it's basically included and expanded upon in every other view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Messageboard') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('general.login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('general.register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('general.logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <main class="py-4">
                @include('inc.statusmessages')
                @yield('content')
            </main>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use App\User;
use Auth;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth', [
            'except' => [
                'index',
                'show'
            ]
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('messages')->with('messages', $messages);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('createmessage');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required|min:15|max:500'
        ]);


        // Create Message
        $message = new Message;
        $message->title = $request->input('title');
        $message->body = $request->input('body');
        $message->status = 100;
        $message->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $message->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Message Created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $message = Message::findOrFail($id);       
        $user = User::findOrFail($message->user_id); 

        $messageData = [
            'message' => $message,
            'user' => $user
        ];

        return view('showmessage')->with($messageData);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $userId = 0;
        $message = Message::findOrFail($id);

        if (Auth::check())
        {
            // The user is logged in...
            $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        }

        if((int)$userId !== (int)$message->user_id) {
            return "Poster ID: ".$message->user_id.", User ID: ".$userId;
        }

        return view('editmessage')->with('message', $message);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required|min:15|max:500'
        ]);

        $message = Message::find($id);
        $message->title = $request->input('title');
        $message->body = $request->input('body');
        $message->status = 100;
        $message->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $message->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Message Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $message = Message::find($id);
        $message->delete();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Message Removed');
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I hope I'm clear enough, and if not please let me know.

Comment: Can you include the blade view causing the error, as well as the controller for the page? Somewhere you're passing an array to `{{ }}`, and it might not even be related to the translation changes you're making

Comment: @TravisBritz yes, certainly. Both have been added.

Comment: Isn't this the issue: `__('Dashboard')`? `Dashboard` is the array and you need to add `Dashboard.someKey` to get a string?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if there's a translation file called `Dashboard.php` then that's very likely, otherwise it should fall back to just the string `"Dashboard"`. So @Tienus, is there a dashboard translation file?

Comment: _"while I haven't even attempted to call it with"_ - One thing you _always_ should do before posting a question is to try as much as possible yourself first. Posting a question here should be the last thing you do, when you're totally stuck.

Comment: Ahh! Yes, that makes sense. I hadn't started translating the file yet. I'll try that.

Comment: @TravisBritz - Isn't `dashboard.php` that file?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You're right, I completely missed that when I came back after the blade file was added. Since you left the comment before me, feel free to post the answer

Comment: Right, so the `{{ __('Dashboard') }}` was indeed what was causing it. Just to clarify though @MagnusEriksson, I'd already called it in my first attempt, but then when I noticed the errors I started working back up until the error was no longer there, if that makes sense. And the thing that removed the error, was removing the translation file altogether. I should've been more clear on that.

Comment: @TravisBritz - You can take it. I haven't worked with Laravel for years so I'm not sure that this is the case or couldn't answer any follow up questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Magnus Eriksson pointed out, this is because you're using `{{ __('Dashboard') }}` in your blade view *and* have a `dashboard.php` translation file.

The `__()` translation helper will normally fall back to returning the string it's given when there are no matching translation keys, but in this case it *does* find the translation file. Since you're not using a specific key from the file such as `dashboard.title`, it's returning the full translation array from the file, which is then given to `htmlentities()` when the blade view is rendered.